Showing that elements match after reducing list (Lean 4)
I'm currently trying to show that the elements of a reduced list match the original list after applying List.take. It feels obvious but it doesn't seem to be definitional and so I've been stuck on this. Here is what I have:
import Mathlib.Init.Order.Defs
import Mathlib.Data.Fintype.Basic

namespace PartialOrder
variable {P : Type*} [PartialOrder P] [Fintype P]

lemma split_tail (L : List P) (n : Fin L.length) (h₀ : n.1 > 0) (h₁ : L.take n ≠ []) : L[n.1-1] = (L.take n).getLast h₁ := by
  have len : (L.take n).length = n := by simp
  sorry 

Any help or advice is appreciated, thanks!

Maybe combine List.get_length_sub_one and List.get_take or List.get_take‘.  I found these with https://Moogle.ai

Also I recommend you prove this for all lists, not just on partial orders.

Alright, thanks! Was mainly proving something about partial orders, but will also try to prove for all lists too.

Here is a proof.  (It is a bit heavy on basic props needed for the Fins used in List.get.  Maybe that can be cleaned up.)
import Mathlib.Tactic

lemma List.nth_eq_take_getlast (L : List α) (n : Fin L.length) (h : (L.take n) ≠ [])
  : (L.take n).getLast h = L[n.1-1] := by
  have h0 : (n : ℕ) > 0 := calc
    (n : ℕ) = (L.take n).length := by simp
    _       > 0                 := length_pos.mpr h  -- found with by apply?
  have h1 : (n : ℕ) - 1 < n := by
    apply Nat.sub_one_lt_of_le  -- found with by apply?
    . exact h0
    . rfl
  have hh0 : (L.take n).length - 1 < (L.take n).length := calc
    (L.take n).length - 1
      = ↑n - 1            := by simp
    _ < ↑n                := h1
    _ = (L.take n).length := by simp
  have hh1 : ↑n - 1 < L.length := calc
    ↑n - 1 < ↑n       := h1
    _      < L.length := by simp
  calc
    (L.take n).getLast h
      = (L.take n).get ⟨(L.take n).length - 1, hh0⟩ := by rw [List.get_length_sub_one hh0]  -- found with Moogle.ai
    _ = L.get ⟨n - 1, hh1⟩                          := by simp [List.get_take'] -- found with Moogle.ai
    _ = L[n.1 -1]                                   := by simp

I used a combination of apply? and https://moogle.ai to find the needed facts.
I also got rid of the unneeded assumptions from the theorem to make it more general and easier to apply.
